# How to use Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes with large amounts of data? (throws OutOfMemoryException)

Tags: c#, arrays, string, out-of-memory

I'm getting out of memory exception while converting string into byte array.

```
if (message.Contains("REQZ1S"))
{
    string strMsg = "REQZID;";
    try
    {
        var tmp = LoadCellService.readFromExcel(LoadCellModel.LoadCellRowList.Where(x => x.Stage == 1).ToList(), 1);
        LogHelper.StartTo(nameof(LoadCellSiemensOPCModel), $"tmp count: {tmp.Item1.Count}");
        if (tmp.Item1 != null)
        {
            tmp.Item1.ForEach(
                z => LoadCellModel.LoadCellRowList.Where(x => x.Stage == z.Stage && x.RowIndex == z.RowIndex).First().LoadCellRowColumnList = z.LoadCellRowColumnList
            );

            LoadCellModel.LoadCellRowList.ForEach(
                x => x.LoadCellRowColumnList.ForEach(y =>
                {
                    LogHelper.StartTo("temp", y.LoadCellRowColumnKey + ";" + y.LoadCellRowColumnValue);
                    if (y.LoadCellRowColumnKey == "Distance")
                    {
                        strMsg += strMsg + ";" + y.LoadCellRowColumnValue;
                    }
                })
            );

            LogHelper.KeyValue(nameof(LoadCellSiemensOPCModel), "message2", strMsg);
            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strMsg + "\r");
            Stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            LogHelper.KeyValue(nameof(LoadCellSiemensOPCModel), "message", strMsg);
            LogHelper.SiemensOPCTrace(nameof(LoadCellSiemensOPCModel), $"Write <<< {strMsg}");
        }
        else
        {
            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("REQZ1E;\r");
            Stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            LogHelper.SiemensOPCTrace(nameof(LoadCellSiemensOPCModel), $"Write <<< REQZ1E;");
        }
        LogHelper.Done(nameof(LoadCellSiemensOPCModel), $"Write <<< REQZ1S;");
    }
    catch (Exception EX)
    {           
        LogHelper.KeyValue(nameof(LoadCellSiemensOPCModel), "message1", strMsg);
        LogHelper.Error("TEMP", EX);
    }
}
```

I suspect that need to add some proper logic more in this part:

```
 byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strMsg + "\r");
 Stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
```

Comment: Why are you using it at all? Why don't you use `StreamWriter`?

Comment: Your problem isn't in `GetBytes`. The problem is you're concatenating strings **very inefficiently** by using `+=` in a loop and you're likely fragmenting the heap. Instead use `StringBuilder` - or as @LLama suggested, rewrite your whole function to use a `StreamWriter`.

Comment: Also you should not be using `List.ForEach` (that method really needs to be removed from .NET imo, there is no reason to use it). Always use a native `foreach` statement instead.

Comment: I just went through your code and correctly re-indented it and I'm mortified - you've got too many nested loops with horrible runtime complexity going on - this program must takes minutes to run when it should only take a few milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks for all the provided solutions. Now I want to add count into my code, got any solution, I am still using my old code, just amend on "strMsg += strMsg + ";" + y.LoadCellRowColumnValue;" TO "strMsg += ";" + y.LoadCellRowColumnValue;" only. 

This is due to later will got sample data like :

[REQZID;3;92.26;;91.79;91.79;;].

The 3 is the total dataset that we have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem **isn't** `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("REQZ1E;\r");` - the problem is here:

```
LoadCellModel.LoadCellRowList.ForEach(
    x => x.LoadCellRowColumnList.ForEach(y => {
    // ...
    strMsg += strMsg + ";" + y.LoadCellRowColumnValue;
    // ...
}
```

Using the `+=` operator to concatenate strings **causes an entire copying and reallocation of the entire string**.

So for example, if you have a loop that iterates 100 times (`10*x` and `10*y` for 100 total) and in each iteration it adds 50 characters to the string (so the final output length is 5000 characters), **but it also copies everything all-over again**, so once you get past, say, 1000 characters the computer now has to copy a whole kilobyte every time - and you got there by copying 999, 998, 997, 996, etc characters too - the runtime complexity for this is pretty awful (on the order of `O(n^2)`).

You can do this instead:

- (Outer `if`, `try/catch` statements and `Logging` calls ommited for brevity)
- I see you're writing to a `Stream`, so use a `StreamWriter` with the desired encoding set.
- I replaced your `.ForEach` calls with `foreach` statements.

```
var tmp = LoadCellService.readFromExcel( LoadCellModel.LoadCellRowList.Where(x => x.Stage == 1 ).ToList() , 1 );

if (tmp.Item1 != null)
{
    // This can be further optimized by loading `LoadCellModel.LoadCellRowList` into a dictionary by an appropriate key.
    foreach( var z in tmp.Item1 )
    {
        var columnList = LoadCellModel.LoadCellRowList
            .Where( x =>
                x.Stage    == z.Stage &&
                x.RowIndex == z.RowIndex
            )
            .First();

        columnList.LoadCellRowColumnList = z.LoadCellRowColumnList;
    }

    using( StreamWriter wtr = new StreamWriter( stream, Encoding.ASCII ) )
    {
        foreach( var x in LoadCellModel.LoadCellRowList )
        {
            foreach( var y in x.LoadCellRowColumnList.Where( yc => yc.LoadCellRowColumnKey == "Distance" ) )
            {
                wtr.Write( ';' );
                wtr.Write( y.LoadCellRowColumnValue );
            }
        }

        wtr.Flush();
    }
}
else
{
    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("REQZ1E;\r");
    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
}
```